# Change Add to Wishlist text in woodmart theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My website is in wordpress. I am using woodmart theme. I want to replace add to wishlist into add to booklist. How to do it? I don't want to use yith wishlist plugin. Because it doesn't match on archive products.

Comment: You always have an option to edit it with javascript but that will may show some lag while the page is loading.

Comment: It looks like Woodmart is a premium theme, so I think you can ask to the developer/support for that.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to disable wishlist go to>>theme settings>>search>>wishlist>>disable wishlist.

**Additional Content**

Search Form Is Here [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWmSK.png)